# ASP.NET Core authentication returrns forbidden

Tags: asp.net-core

I have these auth settings:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Funcs.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Communities");

#region Config authorization   
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        (options) => options
                .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Communities")));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("role", "Admin")
            .Build());
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
#endregion

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        List<string> operationIds = new();
        c.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
            {
                ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = apiDesc.ActionDescriptor;
                var name = $"{actionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}_{apiDesc.RelativePath?.Split('/').LastOrDefault() ?? string.Empty}";
                string? existe = operationIds.FirstOrDefault(x => x == name);
                operationIds.Add(name);
                return name;
            });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Please enter into field the word 'Bearer' following by space and JWT",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
        {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header
        },
        new List<string>()
    }
        });
    });

builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); // Set to 5 minutes
    });

var app = builder.Build();

#region enhance auth
app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
app.UseAuthorization();
#endregion

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(p => p.SerializeAsV2 = true);
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I make login and get a valid `AuthorizationToken` using autorest client.

Then I make another request adding

```
service.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

My request has

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
```

This role exists in my `AspNetRoles` table and my user is registered and in `AspNetUserRoles` it has this `Admin` role assigned.

But my action always returns an http 403 - forbidden error.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the propper `program.cs` settings.

```
///This build my policy or plicies if needed    
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
   .AddPolicy(Policy.Admin, policy => policy
       .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
       .RequireRole(Roles.Admin));

/// This add JWT auth 
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();

///  This adds rolemanager ans user manager services 
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

/// This is required if I add Role manager    
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender<IdentityUser>, CommunitiesEmailSender<IdentityUser>>();
```

Finally must add authenticaton and authorization

```
var app = builder.Build();

#region enhance auth
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
#endregion
```

And Actions or controllers must be marked with `[Authorize(Policy = Policy.Admin )]`

**Note**: `Policy.Admin` and `Roles.Admin` are some constant I write to avoid error typos.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use policy based, you can try this

```
public class BlaBlaController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "AdminPolicy")]
    public ActionResult BlaBla()
    {
    }
}

// Startup

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy",
         policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});
```

Comment: I made the changes and now changed forbidden 403 to Unauthorized 401